# Office 2013 Slow to Open/Save with Folder Redirection

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012-r2, microsoft-office, folder-redirection

We recently deployed folder redirection for a few individuals in the office. We are using a DFS Namespace share on a Server 2012r2 VM. We are redirecting Desktop and My Documents only. Clients are running 8.1 and 7.

When using Word/Excel 2013, there is a popup that says "trying to connect to: \\DFSNAME\userfolder" and its stays there for 1-5 minutes before the browse window opens. This also occurs when trying to attach a file to an email in outlook. There are no delays if the file is double clicked on their desktop.

We've tried the following solutions (whcih seemed to describe our problem perfectly aside from the version):

- http://support2.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;en-US;2308870
- http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2816253

The only thing that is different about this deployment of Folder Redirection is permissions. Instead of following the standard checkbox of exclusive access we used this ancient guide from microsoft - http://support.microsoft.com/kb/288991/. Could our permissions be causing these weird issues?

Comment: Does this occur when opening existing Word files, or also when starting just Word?

Comment: Creating the new document doesn't have any lag, it's only when saving that document. It occurs on both new and existing.

Comment: I had a similar problem once. The reason probably is unrelated, but the troubleshooting could help you. I managed to find a solution running Sysinternal's Process Monitor on the client, aswell as the file server. Try filtering for RESULT != SUCCES, or try more narrow filters. On the client you should be able to see what word.exe is trying to access in detail, and on the server why exactly that fails. Good luck!

Comment: We've had this happen too,  Windows gets quite grumpy when My Docs responds slowly.  Oddly on DFS shares a \\domain\<root> seems to work where a \\domain.com\<root> tends to stall.  It wasn't consistent across the board, but check to see if the shares are accessible when Office is having issue.  We never found a good solution except to remove the .com from the mapping for My Doc and Desktop.

Comment: Any progress on this? Did you see something weird using the Sysinternals tools? Oh, and how many DFS targets do you currently have set up for "\\DFSNAME\userfolder", and are they all reachable from the client computer?

Comment: None yet. Sysinternals hasn't given any new information - it doesn't seem to lagging on a particular file or process. It only has one target, we're using DFS naming for futureproofing right now, not anything fancy. Thank you for following up

Comment: Maybe try adding the DFS/file-server path to Office trusted locations. GUI: File, Options, Trust Center, Trusted Locations. GPO: User Configuration/Administrative Templates/Microsoft Office 2016/Security Settings/Trust Center--Trusted Location #1

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to turn off the File Validation Feature? I've seen it many times with Office 2003 and Office 2007, but I suppose it is still part of Office 2013. You should enter the following in the user's registry:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Excel\Security\FileValidation
REG_DWORD: EnableOnLoad 
Value: 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you ever manage to get to the bottom of this?
We're having this same issue with Server 2016, Office 2016 Pro Plus.
Using folder redirections with a DFS namespace pointing to the location.

```
\\servername\staffdata$
```

Using `\\servername` instead of `\\domainname` doesn't make a difference, however if you delete the DFS namespace suddenly `\\servername` works perfectly. But obviously we can't use `\\domainname` without the DFS namespace.

I found that changing the DFS mode from 2008 to 2000 made some difference initially, but it is just as slow as 2008 mode now.

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault and for your interest in it. However, your post does not answer the question that was asked and so should not be posted as an answer. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). See also: [ask].

Answer (score 0):

try to turn off option in
Internet properties -> Connections -> LAN Setings -> Autmaticly detect settings (CHECK BOX need to be unchecked)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By my own experience, a way for me to solve this slow file load is to regularly update the data in a new workbook/document every once in a while (for me its about once a week or a month), because at some point files that are especially shared through the server cloud could not load well when data stored in a single document is too much for the server to handle. I hope this might help you or anyone else who shared the same problem.